# Cannot show OHLC Values with stocklegend

Tags: javascript, amcharts, stock

I have some trouble in showing OHLC values with stocklegend in amchart.
When I set as **stockLegend.valueTextRegular = undefined;**, I can see some values and I can't guess what it is. (figure1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tMk2.png)
I have tried to set as **stockLegend.valueTextRegular = "Open: [[open]]";**, the result was like figure2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH5gz.png)
what's wrong with my work?

source codes are below:

```js
        chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();


        // DATASET //////////////////////////////////////////
        dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet.fieldMappings = [{
            fromField: "open",
            toField: "open"
        }, {
            fromField: "close",
            toField: "close"
        }, {
            fromField: "high",
            toField: "high"
        }, {
            fromField: "low",
            toField: "low"
        }, {
            fromField: "volume",
            toField: "volume"
        }, {
            fromField: "value",
            toField: "value"
        }];
        dataSet.color = "#7f8da9";
        dataSet.dataProvider = chartData;
        dataSet.title = "Stock";
        dataSet.categoryField = "date";
        
        var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
        
                stockPanel.title = "Value";
        stockPanel.showCategoryAxis = false;
        stockPanel.percentHeight = 70;

        var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
        stockPanel.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

        stockPanel.categoryAxis.dashLength = 5;

        // graph of first stock panel
        var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph.type = "candlestick";
        graph.openField = "open";
        graph.closeField = "close";
        graph.highField = "high";
        graph.lowField = "low";
        graph.valueField = "close";
        graph.lineColor = "#7f8da9";
        graph.fillColors = "#7f8da9";
        graph.negativeLineColor = "#db4c3c";
        graph.negativeFillColors = "#db4c3c";
        graph.proCandlesticks = true;
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        graph.useDataSetColors = false;
        graph.comparable = true;
        graph.compareField = "value";
        graph.showBalloon = true;
        graph.balloonText = "Open:<b>[[close]]</b>";
        stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);

        var stockLegend = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
        stockLegend.valueTextRegular = "Open: [[open]]";
        //stockLegend.valueTextRegular = undefined;
        stockLegend.periodValueTextComparing = "[[percents.value.close]]%";
        stockPanel.stockLegend = stockLegend;

        var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
        chartCursor.valueLineEnabled = true;
        chartCursor.valueLineAxis = valueAxis;
        stockPanel.chartCursor = chartCursor;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you're having. `[[open]]` shows the open value for me; similarly `[[close]]`, `[[high]]`,`[[low]]` and `[[value]]` also display their associated values ([docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockLegend#valueTextRegular)). `undefined`  in `valueTextRegular` defaults to `[[value]]`. See my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ad238142c9329b95d8b51161a3801f11?editors=0010).

Comment: Hi xorspark, thanks for your kind reply and I found the reason by myself.
It was wrongly working because of thymeleaf parsing. Thymeleaf parsed **[[** to **"**.
So **[[open]]** was parsed to **"open"**.

Comment: I used Spring + Thymeleaf in this project. Thanks.

Comment: @zap, how did you solve the thymeleaf issue?